# Unable to install Nodejs using Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, cordova

Hi I am new here so apologies if I made any mistakes in my post.

I am currently trying to dockerize a Cordova environment.
I am currently able to build the image but it throws me this error: `Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

This is due to Nodejs not installing during the build (which is strange as I can see the installation process in my console.

I removed `CMD ["npm", "--version"]` from my code and rebuilt the image. When I bashed into the container, I confirmed that Nodejs is indeed not installed.

I tried to remove `USER root` but it resulted in the Android SDK failing to install.

This is my current code in my Dockerfile.

```
FROM gradle:4.10.0-jdk8

USER root

ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=29 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3

# Download Android SDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true \
    && echo "24333f8a63b6825ea9c5514f83c2829b004d1fee" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
#    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

# Install Android Build Tool and Libraries
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools"

# Install Build Essentials
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y && apt-get install file -y && apt-get install apt-utils -y


# Set working directory
WORKDIR /cordova

# Copy all files inside
COPY . .

# Install nodejs and cordova
RUN  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash \
    && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install node \
    && npm install -g cordova

CMD ["npm", "--version"]
```

Thank for your time and help!

Comment: Version managers like `nvm` don't interact well with Docker.  The `. nvm.sh` setup doesn't last beyond the end of its `RUN` instruction in this case.  I'd just download and install the specific version of Node you need, or use whatever version `apt-get install nodejs` gives you.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your advice! I tried `apt-get install nodejs` and it is installed in the docker image. However, I couldn't get npm running. I searched around stackoverflow and did not find anything that works (Mainly `apt-get install npm` but I get the error `Unable to locate package npm`). Sorry if the solution has been around in stackoverflow but I would like to ask for some direction on the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi all, I have successfully installed Nodejs using the following:
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/sietup_14.x | bash -` and then
`apt-get install -y nodejs` from this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/720784/how-to-install-latest-node-inside-a-docker-container. Thanks!